# Add textfield inside Cell(TCPDF)

Tags: php

I have a dynamic cell based on the user input, for example if the user wants 3 rows, it will display 3 rows on PDF. The problem is I need to make that cell fillable.

```
$pdf->setFormDefaultProp(array('lineWidth'=>1, 'borderStyle'=>'solid', 'fillColor'=>array(255, 255, 200), 'strokeColor'=>array(255, 128, 128)));
for ($r=1;$r<=$row;$r++) {
for ($c=1;$c<=$col;$c++) {
$w = 180/2;
$h = 200/$row;
//$nemsung2=$_POST['subjects'];
//$pdf->Cell($w, $h, '' .$nemsung2  ,1,0, 'L');
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$sample = $pdf->TextField('firstname', 50, 5);
$pdf->Cell($w, $h,$sample, 1,0, 'C');
```

My question is how can I add textfield inside a cell dynamically? thx

Comment: whats wrong with your current code? any errors?

Comment: I want to make the cell fillable, I thought of adding textfield inside the cell but can't make it work..:(

Comment: it is the from TCPDF. I am generating a PDF.

Comment: now the textbox is disabled or something? that you can fill it?

Comment: in that code, the textfield was displaying beside the cell, what I want is to place the textfield inside the cell ..

Comment: you know I don't know much about creating pdf. But others now would understand your question better.